# Fat as hydrocarbon rocket fuel?

Tags: rockets, liquid-fuel

Have fat/grease or fatty acids ever been studied as a liquid rocket fuel?

(I don't expect it to be a *good* rocket fuel, but I wonder if anybody has ever burned it in an engine or made a serious study of it.)

(I'm aware of amateur experimenters making hybrid rockets or similar devices using bacon and gaseous oxygen, that's not what this question is about.)

Comment: Designers of fuel turbopumps and injectors would prefer hydrocarbons with low viscosity.

Comment: @Uwe Certainly, but that has not prevented gelatinous and particle-loaded slurry fuels from being experimented as described in Ignition. Plus, depending on the fatty acid it isn't necessarily *that* viscous when heated.

Comment: Anything combustible can be used as rocket fuel. Good example is sugar plus nitrite rockets used by some primitive land attack rockets. This is definitely the kind of study that haven't been worth doing for the entire history of rocketry so probably is not done yet. Hey, if anyone answers this question and list some performance estimations, he/she could be the first and only one to study this subject.

Comment: BTW if you want to apply biofuel to rockets this is definitely a starting point.

Comment: @user3528438 "Anything combustible can be used as rocket fuel."? Good luck when trying woodchips, straw, peat, brown coal, charcoal or saw dust. Bunker oil used by large ships will be not easy too.

Comment: @Uwe charcoal rocket = black powder fireworks

Comment: Yes, but that's clearly not even slightly like a liquid fuel rocket.

Comment: Amateur rocketry enthusiasts used fatty, well-preserved (nitrate-rich) salami as hybrid rocket fuel.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! There are various studies conducted on the viability of fatty acids / parrafins / biodiesels as rocket fuels. Bio rocket fuel is an actual thing!

[image]

[This study shows that](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2007/03/070319175853.htm)

> virtually any *lipid-based* feedstock, or raw material with a fat source -- including what is perceived as low-quality feedstock like cooking grease -- and turn it into virtually any fuel.
>   Using low-quality feedstock is typically 30 percent less costly than using corn or canola oils to make fuel.
>
> First, the engineers use **high temperatures and high water pressure to strip off the so-called free fatty acids from the accumulated feedstock of oils and fats**, or triglycerides. Next, the engineers place **the free fatty acids in a reactor to perform the decarboxylation step; that is, carbon dioxide is taken off the free fatty acids**. Depending on the feedstock used, the scientists are left with alkanes, or straight-chain hydrocarbons of either *15 or 17 carbon atoms.

In the last two steps, the engineers **break up the straight chains into molecules with branches, making them more compact and changing their chemical and physical characteristics**. Jet fuel and biodiesel fuel require a mixture of molecules with between 10 and 14 carbon atoms, while gasoline requires only eight carbon atoms, so the engineers can control the process to elicit exactly the type of fuel they desire.

Finally, the engineers make some other *chemical tweak* to create the desired fuel. Also, the glycerol by-product ( from the first two process ) is burned off to provide heat for the various processes involved.

[This study shows that biofuels can be used to make liquid rocket fuels](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/283217298_The_Analysis_of_Use_of_Liquid_Biofuels_for_Liquid_Rockets_Propulsion)

In fact the  ***most  advanced  liquid  biofuel, SPK  (Synthetic  Paraffinic  Kerosene)*** type, is chemically  very  similar  to  the  **RP-1.**

> Chemically,  biodiesel  is  composed  of  **monoalkyl  esters** of  long  chains  and  **fatty  acids** derived  from  renewable  feed  stock  like  vegetable  oils  and  animal  fats.  It  is  produced  by *transestrification,*  in  which  oil  or  fat  is  reacted  with  a  monohydric  alcohol  in  presence  of  a catalyst.  Biodiesel  is  used  in  compression  ignition  engines  (diesel  engines)  or  heating  boilers. The  biodiesel  fuel  has  in  general,  the  same  or  similar  properties  of  the  conventional  diesel  fuel and  can  be  blended  in  any  percentage  with  diesel  fuel. **Rocket  Propellant  -  1,  (RP-1)**  is  similar  to  gasoline.  It  is  a  fuel  constituted  basically  of hydrocarbons  and  a  small  portion  of  oxygenized  compounds.  These  hydrocarbons  are,  in general,  lighter  fuels  than  those  that  compose  biodiesel  fuel,  because  they  are  formed  by molecules  of  small  carbonic  chains  *(normally  has  12,  or  slightly  less,  carbon  atoms).*  Because of  the  lack  of  light  hydrocarbons,  *RP-1  has  a  high  flash  point,  and  is  less  of  a  fire  hazard  than gasoline*  or  even  some  jet  and  diesel  fuels.

Also Parrafins and other fatty acids can be used to make hybrid rocket motors composed of solid rocket fuel. 
Generally,
Common fuels for a typical hybrid rocket engine include polymers such as *acrylic, polyethylene (PE),* cross-linked rubber such as **HTPB**(most common) or liquefying fuels such as **paraffin wax** is also used.

[image]

[image]

[**This study on : Feasibility Study of Palm-Based Fuels for Hybrid Rocket 
Motor Applications**](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.5022904) gives a detailed overview.
*I highly recommend going through this awesome article*

> **Palm oil Wax** or in **stearic acid** are scientific names derived from palm oil products by several processes. These 
>   Wax are in the simplest terms the type of high purity of **vegetable fatty acids**, especially **triglycerides.** They are palm 
>   oil products after being processed under flux pressure and extreme temperature pressures. From that process, *Wax 
>   based on vegetables, vegan, 100% wax are produced.*
>   **Stearic acid** or stearine  ($C _{18} H_{36} O_2$) is widely used in addition to the increase of combustion time, wax 
>   sharpener and helps improve the retention of fragrance in the extinguished wax. **Stearine** is actually derived from 
>   *unscrupulous oils* obtained by a process where oil palm bunches are pressed in the same way as pressed olive oil. It 
>   then becomes a bleach-like by *absorbent clay,* which removes dyes and impurities. Initially, the fruit is in bright 
>   orange because it contains a high amount of carotene. The oil is then discarded and sterilized by heating it at high 
>   temperatures. Lastly, a process called *'fractionation'* is done to separate the fat from the liquid.
>
> The fatty acids contained in palm oil comprise a large number of **triglycerides** (vegetable fat), each having their 
>   own melting point. At high temperatures, triglycerides will crystallize and crystals can be formed by the continuous 
>   cooling process around the pipe coil, which separates oil into different fractions. When the temperature is reduced, 
>   fat will continue to strengthen that will isolate the oil into liquid fat and vegetables that are present in solid state at 
>   room temperature. We can see the result as a palm wax, produced, from fractionation but without any additions or 
>   chemical solvents added.

[image]

Also there are certain **avantages** of using biofuels:

1. They are "**clean**".
2. Being of a **higher density** a smaller fuel tank can accommodate a larger amount of fuel, thus *reducing the weight* of the tank itself.
   [Biodiesel  is  also  about  9%  denser  than  the  RP-1](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/283217298_The_Analysis_of_Use_of_Liquid_Biofuels_for_Liquid_Rockets_Propulsion)

[**Advancing Europe’s Hybrid Rocket Engine Technology with﻿ Paraffin and LOX**](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://elib.dlr.de/130301/1/EUCASS2019-0682%2520Schmierer.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjj48rQ2YrpAhX6zjgGHbgUBvkQFjABegQIDhAG&usg=AOvVaw1Dhk_xzDsgiI-h8eyklLjC)
*Do go through this article. Highly recommended!*

Comment: "Have fat/grease or fatty acids ever been studied as a liquid rocket fuel?" These hybrid rockets use a solid fuel, they don't work with liquid fuels.

Comment: @Uwe the first part of my answer deals with liquid bio rocket fuel and bio diesel and how they compare to RP-1.....then I've also included parrafins based solid/hybrid rocket motor (cuz it's relatively more 'popular' .

Comment: @Uwe one thing to note is that although the fuels have a organic origin (fats basically), they often have to be highly modified chemically to make them useful.

Comment: This is beautiful but not an answer. It deals not with fat as a fuel but with fat as a raw material out of which hydrocarbon fuels can be made. Not the same thing at all.